# Why do I fail to get the derivative of sec(x) using the power rule?

Tags: derivatives, trigonometry

So, the power rule seems to state:

$\frac{d}{dx}x^n = nx^{n-1}$

Since $\sec{x} = \frac{1}{\cos x}$, and the power rule is true, shouldn't the derivative be:

$\frac{d}{dx}\sec{x} = \frac{d}{dx}\frac{1}{\cos x}=\frac{d}{dx}(\cos x)^{-1} = -\cos^{2}x = -\sec^{2}x$

But instead, the derivative is given as $\sec x \tan x$ in my textbook. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You forgot to use Chain Rule when needed.

Comment: It's true that $\frac{d}{d(\cos x)}(\cos x)^{-1}=-\cos^2x$, but not $\frac{d}{dx}(\cos x)^{-1}$, because the function $(\cos x)^{-1}$ is composite in terms of $x$ and you need the Chain Rule.

Comment: In general, the derivative of $1/f(x)$ is $-f'(x)/(f(x))^2$. It’s the Chain Rule in action.